# References on Martin's Axiom and the product of ccc spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, set-theory

It is a well known result in Set Theory that MA$_{\aleph_1}$ implies that any product of ccc spaces is ccc.

After digging on Jech's book (Set Theory, 3rd Millenium edition), I found a mention about an intermediate result, involving the Knaster property (MA$_{\aleph_1}$ implies that any ccc space has the Knaster property), saying that it is due to "Kunen, Rowbottom, Solovay and possibly others".

So, I would like to know whom first proved that "MA$_{\aleph_1}$ implies that any product of ccc spaces is ccc", or if it is *safe* to assume it as "folklore".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look in Fremlin's book, "Consequences of Martin's Axiom" which has a whole history of these results, including who proved what when etc. It was already known that a product of ccc spaces is ccc iff every finite subproduct is ccc, using the $\Delta$-system lemma. Showing that a ccc PO has property (K) (Knaster) which implies that ccc is finitely productive, is one of the main applications of $\text{MA}_{\aleph_1}$. The chapter on MA in the handbook of Set theoretic topology is also quite good. (I have both books, but cannot look in them right now).

Comment: I just _found_ them here. Thank you!

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba You're welcome.